# cómo capturar un array en nodejs

Tags: array, nodejs, postman

Lo que estoy intentado es guardar un array enviada desde postman con el verbo POST en una variable. Sin embargo, no he podido por un error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

En postman, lo he realizado asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de esta forma quiero capturar el array de materias del alumno.

```
app.post('/alumnos',(req,res)=>{
    
    var materias=req.body.materiasCursa
        
      var i=0
      var materiasModificado = materias.map (
            el => {
                return {
                    "orden": i+1,
                    "nombreMateria": el.nombreMateria,
                    "aprobada": false
                }
            }
          )
           
       alumnos.push({
            "nombre": req.body.nombre,
            "legajo":req.body.legajo,
            "materiasCursa": materiasModificado
        })

        res.status(200).json("Insertado correctamente")
        
     
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya me di cuenta cual fue tu error realmente, es un error de postman,en la imagen que subiste, tienes el formato en **text**,  debes cambiarlo a **JSON**, por favor sigue estos [pasos](https://abi.gitbook.io/net-core/4.-creando-tu-primer-servicio/4.4-probando-tus-servicios-con-postman#probar-el-servicio-post).

Comment: Excelente! Me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias :-)

Comment: Bien, buena suerte!